# how to remove dropdown list from input forms, without jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I trying to create an html/JavaScript terminal/shell. I want to use an input box and form, to reference to JavaScript functions/commands , and I am not aware of how to remove the drop down menu that appears after a previous input

image of terminal:

[image: image is terminal]

Does anyone know how to do this without Jquery, or is that the only possible method.

Comment: just simply put this in your form html tag: `autocomplete="off"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
```